# Webaudio: createMediaElementSource faster than XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

Whenever I play music using XMLHttpRequest I must wait at least 10 seconds or so until I hear the sound.

- Short sounds load instantly.
- The larger sound (3 minutes) takes at least 10 seconds before it plays.

What are some factors that play a role in loading time? I mean im doing this in a localhost. Sound should play back instantly as im not downloading anything. Obviously the time for the script running though is equal for large and small sounds.

I did notice that using createMediaElementSource considerably speeds it up and sounds play instantly.

So what is going on?

Comment: @ZebRawnsley its a bit long this is why I didnt post it. Anyways, I hope this somehow helps illustrate the problem.

Comment: @ZebRawnsley too hard? You think it can be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How big is the audio file in question? If it's large, you're probably paying a big price for `decodeAudioData`.

With `createMediaElementSource()`, you get to decode the audio file in chunks. It'll start playing back as soon as it thinks it has enough of a buffer to play through to the end.

But with `decodeAudioData`, you have to wait until the *whole file* gets decoded.

Comment: An MP3 file of 4 megabytes. I also tried smaller files. It seems the smaller the filer the sooner it plays.

Comment: Is there no work-around for decodeAudioData so that I start to hear chunks? Similar to createMediaElementSource? I mean I would just use createMediaElementSource but it seems safari doesnt support it.

Comment: You could break the audio up into a number of smaller files. Like, maybe break it up into 4 separate 1MB audio files and load them in order. Then you can start playback after the first one loads, and while that's playing, you load the other ones.

You could also look into the `createMediaElementSource` issue in Safari. It should work.

Comment: But did you see the caniuse website?

Comment: If you go to "known issues" http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api it will say that safari doesnt support it

Comment: I really do like the idea of breaking the file up into pieces. What I dont know is how to check if the audio has loaded.